# СУБД Interbase 2009

Tags: interbase

Имеется ПО, которое при помощи СУБД Interbase 2009, непрерывно записывает в БД (БД-получатель) информацию. Необходимо через период заменить БД-получатель на пустую БД, при этом ПО не должно прерывать работу.

Возможно ли такое реализовать? Если да, то при помощи чего?

Comment: Забрать данные из этой бд и опустошить ее, зачем что-то поменять?

Comment: Забирать данные, это долго (например, 10000 записей). Быстрее мгновенно подменить БД.

Comment: Подмена "на лету" чревата проблемами. И запросто может нарваться как на sharing violation со стороны подменяющего ПО, так и на fatal error сервиса сервера. Тогда как удаление записей из таблиц (в правильном порядке с учётом связей) безопасно. Если реализовать это в формате хранимой процедуры, запускаемой асинхронно, то с точки зрения клиента процесс произойдёт мгновенно. А процедуру можно запускать и из планировщика.

Comment: А каким образом скопировать удаляемые данные?